# Integral involving $u^{-u}$

Tags: definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve the following definite integral

$$\int_0^{\infty}u^{-u+a}\,du$$
with $a>0$.

Using integration by parts I've arrived

$$\int_0^{\infty}u^{-u+a}\,du=\frac{1}{1+a}\int_0^{\infty}u^{-u+a+1}(1+\ln(u))\,du$$

which is a worst integral.

Maybe a change of variable, but I don't know how to follow.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no elementary integral for $u^{-u}$

Comment: Do you wanna say that it's not possible express in terms of elementary functions? And...in terms of special functions?

Comment: Notice that the minimum value of the integral correspond to $a \approx \log(2)$. Why ? This is a question.

Answer (score 1):

This looks even worse than the [sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) and only numerical methods could be used.

Let $$I_a=\int_0^{\infty}u^{-u+a}\,du$$

For small values of $a$, you would get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & I_a \\
 0.00 & 1.99546 \\
 0.25 & 1.81433 \\
 0.50 & 1.73133 \\
 0.75 & 1.71513 \\
 1.00 & 1.75183 \\
 1.25 & 1.83622 \\
 1.50 & 1.96842 \\
 1.75 & 2.15247 \\
 2.00 & 2.39609
\end{array}
\right)$$

For large values of $a$, the integral varies extremely fast
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & I_a \\
 0 & 1.99546 \\
 1 & 1.75183 \\
 2 & 2.39609 \\
 3 & 4.27169 \\
 4 & 9.22902 \\
 5 & 23.2062 \\
 6 & 66.1712 \\
 7 & 210.120 \\
 8 & 733.083 \\
 9 & 2781.12 \\
 10 & 11378.2
\end{array}
\right)$$